# British use of the word rubber

Tags: meaning

I just finished watching The Legend of Tarzan film and am in a disagreement with my son over the meaning of the word rubber in the following sentence spoken by Lord Greystoke/Tarzan: "And when you're finished, chew the flowers into a poultice and wipe it on the cut with a rubber."

Does rubber mean a spatula-type instrument?

Comment: I've heard the term used to refer to a eraser. But, haven't seen the film so I'm not sure if that is correct in this circumstance.

Comment: The word might have been mis-heard, unless you saw it stated in sub-titled.  I'd suggest the word was "rub", not "rubber".  The film wasn't exactly noted for the quality of the script...

Comment: @Pete This source suggests you are correct http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-legend-of-tarzan

Comment: @Spagirl - I did see that site on my research travels, but didn't quote it as I don't think it's an official source - I believe it's just someone transcribing from the film.  It does seem reasonable interpretation though (although not the wording I'd use).  In the old TV episodes, Tarzan wasn't great at spoken English ("Me Tarzan, you Jane"), but he does seem more educated in the quote above.

Comment: @Pete, I've seen other sources which do cite 'rubber', but it just seems odd. I can see why Terri is confused, but  if you have to chew the poultice rather than use a mortar and pestle, would you *have* a spatula? I wonder if the line started out with 'rubber leaf'? Were they in the right sort of jungles for *Ficus elastica*?

Comment: @Spagirl - Real [rubber plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hevea_brasiliensis) are native to the Amazon rainforest, although if this were the meaning in the film, we could put that down to "poetic license" (or a "script goof).  However, we might be digressing here.  I still think that the most likely use of the word is a verb (i.e. rub the poultice in with a rub) rather than as a noun (rubbing the poultice in using an implement called a "rubber").  Either way, the grammar quoted isn't great.  This could be the script, it could be the actor.

Comment: Surely just a noun-from-verb usage, 'something to rub [something on] with'. [M-W](polishing, scraping, or cleaning) has:  << ... [1b] an [any] instrument or object (such as a rubber eraser) used in rubbing, polishing, scraping, or cleaning >> As Spagirl hints, here, this is more likely to be a suitable handy object (a firm leaf?) rather than some medical or even kitchen instrument. No doubt a mortar and pestle, with distilled water and some antiseptic, would be preferable to one's chewing, but the middle of the jungle leaves one with fewer options.

Answer (score 3):

British English uses the word *rubber* as follows:

1. To refer to the raw material harvested from the juice/sap of rubber trees which are grown in their millions on plantations in Asia. Much of this raw material is processed and manufactured into car tyres (BrE)/car tires (AmE) which, for the most part, are made of *rubber*. There are many other products, large and small, that are made from rubber;
2. What our American friends call an eraser, we the Brits call a *rubber*. Generations of school kids have kept a rubber in their pencil cases, ready at hand to rub out (erase) mistakes in spelling that occur when the child is learning to write on paper with a pencil;
3. Is slang and/or a less formal way of referring to a condom. The *Durex* brand of condom or *rubber* is the market leader in the UK and is made by the London Rubber Co. Ltd. The use of the word *rubber* in this context is more common in AmE.
4. The word *rubber* is used in connection with a series of games or sports. It is also used in card games like Bridge;
5. A *rubber* spatula is a tool that is commonly used in cooking.

*Rubber:* "an elastic substance (= that stretches) made either from the juice of particular tropical trees or artificially; UK an eraser; slang for a condom; a series of three or five games between two teams, especially in card games". (Dictionary Cambridge)

*Rubber spatula:* [used in cooking] "It has a broad, flat and usually flexible rubber blade that is used for blending food or removing it from cooking vessels such as pans, bowls or cans". (www.reference.com)

With regard to the OP’s Tarzan quote, the context is obviously some kind or First Aid treatment in the field administered to someone who has sustained a cut. Tarzan comes to the rescue and suggests a poultice which is to be spread on the cut by means of a *rubber* spatula.

Comment: This source http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-legend-of-tarzan gives the line as 'with a rub'. Which makes sense, if you are in a jungle setting and chewing flowers to a poultice, would you have a rubber spatula handy?

Comment: @Spagirl Quite so! Now if it had been Superman in the jungle instead of Tarzan, that errant rubber spatula might have been conjured up out of thin air.

Comment: @PeterPoint Oddly I've never heard a joke told about anyone confused between the British and American interpretations of *a rubber*. There ought to be dozens.

Comment: @WS2 Indeed there ought to be, but I just can't think of one off the top of my head!